# Trying to add a Payment on QBO Credit Memo

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to add a payment with Credit Memo type but it always throws an error like this.

> {"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"A business validation error has
>   occurred while processing your request","Detail":"Business Validation
>   Error: The Amount Received (plus credits) can't be less than the
>   selected charges. Also, the selected charges can't be less than the
>   selected
>   credits.","code":"6000","element":""}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2017-09-13T21:33:58.047-07:00"}

here is my sample post body request

```
{
    "CustomerRef":
    {
        "value": "73",
    "name": "John Doe"
    },
    "TotalAmt": 1100.0,
    "Line": [
    {
        "Amount": 1100.0,
        "LinkedTxn": [
        {
            "TxnId": "250",
            "TxnType": "CreditMemo"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I also try it on the API explorer https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=Payment, it throws the same error. Please give me an idea on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: You've not specified the invoice id that you're trying to pay. Could that be it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @MatthewSteeples